# JavaScript ternary operator and if/else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary

Can anyone explain to me what is the difference between these two statements and why the second one does not work and the first one does:

1. `if (finalWord.length > 140) return false;
   else return finalWord;`
2. `(finalWord.length > 140) ? false : finalWord;`

Comment: They do the same thing. The second one doesn't work because you are not returning anything

Comment: You miss the `return` statement in the second example. It should be `return (finalWord.length > 140) ? false : finalWord;`

Comment: The second version is missing the return statement. It should be `return (finalWord.length > 140) ? false : finalWord;` or `return finalWord.length > 140 && finalWord;`

Comment: Also, see [Conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks, you miss the [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

```
return finalWord.length > 140 ? false : finalWord;
```

You could shorten it to

```
return finalWord.length <= 140 && finalWord;
```

Comment: I am so stupid :)) I thought that the return statement was implicit when using ternary operator. thanks

Comment: @Dito if it was, then you wouldn't be able to write `var myVar = someVariable == otherVariable ? "yes" : "no";`